# JavaScript: Accessing Object [Object] from local storage in html5

Tags: javascript, local-storage

i've got this code to list all saved players in a game:

```
function getAllPlayers(){
for (var i = 0; i <= playerCount; i++){
  object[i] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("savedData"+i));
  console.log(object[i]);
   }
}
```

I get object[object], which is a collection of objects. In console, I get to see their properties and values, however with:

```
for (var name in object) {
  alert('"' + name + '"="' + object[name] + '"');
}
```

I still cannot access these properties. Is there a method to get each object into a separate variable, so that I can access them via varName.property syntax?

Comment: Calling your variable `object` is probably not the best idea.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference - still getting [object Object] when changed the var name.

Comment: Using "object" as var name will work. As long as you don't try to use "Object"... I really wouldn't recommend it though.

Comment: EDIT: it returns: key: 0
value: [object Object]

Comment: How do you put your objects into `locaStorage` ?

Comment: I use       localStorage.setItem("savedData"+i, JSON.stringify([new Player(playerName)]));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because `object` is not really an object this is **array of objects** and you should access property of some object in this array

```
for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++)
  for (var name in object[i]) {
    alert('"' + name + '"="' + object[i][name] + '"');
  }   

 //currently you have to read it like this
 for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++){
   var singleObj = object[i][0];  // additional 0 index 
   for (var name in singleObj) {
    alert('"' + name + '"="' + singleObj[name] + '"');
  }   
  }
```

like you are using it here

```
console.log(object[i]);
```

Comment: I was looking for something of the sort, but it does output "0"="[object Object]", not the actual properties. Unfortunately. I tried eval() as well, no luck with that neither.

Comment: you are enumerating entire array instead of single object from array, or maybe your objects are arrays to try add additional index like `singleObj[0]`

Comment: Your are storing arrays in array with `JSON.stringify([new Player(playerName)]))` just store it like `JSON.stringify(new Player(playerName)))` and you will not need this additional index to dig out real data out this nested arrays

Comment: This answer above sorts it out with no need to use second iteration. I would check it as the right answer for this post. thanks VitaliyG

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that you are getting `[object Object]` in your `alert()` box:

`alert(someObject)` calls native `Object.toString()` method of an argument passed, that is why you are getting `[object Object]`.

Use `JSON.stringify(someObject)` to simply convert your object to JSON string, or implement your own method to generate a string from an object.

Comment: I use the same method to save the object in local storage, ie : localStorage.setItem("savedData"+i, JSON.stringify([new Player(playerName)])); I reckoned that parsing from Json does the opposite. Using stringify displays the object alright but I still cannot access it's values through the dot syntax. Is there a way to do that?